# Why can I not access a field of my mysqli result with $row['price'+$i+'dollar'] with PHP?

Tags: php

In a database I'm working with, there are 6 columns with names:

```
price1dollar
price2dollar
price3dollar
price4dollar
price5dollar
price6dollar
```

I thought that once I had the result set for the query, I could access it like so with PHP:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    echo $row['price'+$i+'dollar'].'<br />';
}
```

and that would print out all the values, but I'm not getting anything printed.

if I use:

```
echo $row['price1dollar'];
```

then the value is printed out fine.

I have `echo`ed the value of `$i` and it prints out 1 to 6 fine, so I don't know whats going on.

Is the `$row['price'+$i+'dollar']` syntax not allowed?

Many thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

should be

```
$row['price' . $i . 'dollar']
```

in PHP there are `.` (dot) string connections (`+` (plus) is i think for example in Java)

Comment: *"`+` (plus) is i think in Java"* and a bunch of other languages actually (Python, JavaScript, ...)

Comment: Ah. I don't believe it. So stupid. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: In JavaScript, the `+` operator overload is a source of endless frustration.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, the `+` symbol is the [addition operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and it doesn't make sense to perform arithmetic operations on strings. It won't trigger a syntax error since PHP will try to convert your strings into numbers (e.g. `'price'` becomes `0`) but it won't render anything useful.

You probably want the `.` symbol which corresponds to the [concatenation operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

See also the [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) function, which is very useful to find out what your data contains.